# Not able to call simple web api post method from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-web-api

Firstly I am unable to pass the model from jquery to my web-api, so I changed my code and write a simple controller with GET and POST

```
using ContactInfo.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace ContactInfo.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Contact")]
    public class ContactController : ApiController
    {
        List<ContactDto> contactList = new List<ContactDto>
       {
            new ContactDto { ContactId = 1, ContactName = "x", MobileNumber="1234567890" },
            new ContactDto { ContactId = 1, ContactName = "y", MobileNumber="1234567890" },
       };
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetProducts")]
        public IEnumerable<ContactDto> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return contactList;
        }
        [Route("AddProduct")]
        [HttpPost]
        public string Add(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!--<button id="Result" value="Submit" />-->
    <input id="Result" name="Result" type="button" value="Submit" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var name = 'hi';
            $("#Result").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:51856/api/Contact/AddProduct',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: name,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('hello');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error I am getting is as follow on submitting the form

> "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:51856/api/Contact/AddProduct'.","MessageDetail":"No
>   action was found on the controller 'Contact' that matches the
>   request."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are doing it wrong. There are 2 ways to achieve this.

- 1st Method -

Add a model class StudentModel.cs

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then Accept that parameter as Model -

```
[Route("AddProduct")]
[HttpPost]
public string Add(StudentModel model)
{
    return "";
}
```

and in Jquery Request ->

```
var postData = {};
postData.name = "Tom";
$("#Result").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Contact/AddProduct',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('hello');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

- 2nd Method ->
  pass name as parameter in URl `url: '/api/Contact/AddProduct?name=' + name` and accept the paramter as string in Action AddProduct (Not Recommended as it is a POST request)

Comment: Thanks how can I pass model with list like `public class EmployeeDto
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
        public List<ContactDto> contactDtos { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: var EmployeeDto = {};
EmployeeDto.EmployeeId = "Tom";
EmployeeDto.EmployeeEmail = 'tom@gmail.com';

var contactDtos = [];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 var ContactDto {
  name : 'User' + i,
  age : '18;
 }
 contactDtos.push(ContactDto);
}
EmployeeDto.contactDtos = contactDtos; @Learner Sorry for syntax atleast you will get some idea